# How to get meta_key and its meta_value within wp_usermeta by ajax call (json format)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, wordpress

In Wordpress I have created some custom fields within my Theme Edit Profile page which, one of them, allows me to enter a user address.
This address is automatically stored in WordPress DB under table wp_usermeta. (custom field is called user_address).

From wp_usermeta, the column called meta_key has a value 'user_address'. But the content I"m trying to collect is its meta_value equivalent.

Screenshot:

[image]

Here my php code to convert the data into JSON format:

```
...... 
$row=$db->prepare('select * from wp_usermeta'); 
......

foreach($row as $rec)//foreach loop  
   {  
     $json_array['meta_key']=$rec['meta_key'];
     array_push($json_data,$json_array); 
   }
```

From the JS file:

```
request('file.php', function(data) {

  var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       console.log(data[i].meta_key);
  }
........
```

My problem is here. From data[i] I need to get all the 'user_address' (within meta_key) and the equvalent value stored in meta_value as shown in the screeshot above, but unfortunately I don't know how to get it.
I can get all the meta_key values, but I don't know how to associate user_address to meta_value.

I've tried:

```
data[i].meta_key.user_address.meta_value
data[i].user_address.meta_value
data[i].meta_key[user_address].meta_value
data[i].meta_key['user_address'].meta_value
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Dear, for the debug, add `var data = {}` as global. Then set data when you receive it in that global variable. Finally, in chrome, write `data` in the console (Chrome/Firefox). You will be able to see how `data` really is. If the data is NULL, then use [Simple JSON for PHP](https://github.com/AlexisTM/Simple-Json-PHP) to forge your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the `user_address` in your table is not a key, it is the value of `meta_key`. Your end result, thinking logically, is that you want the `meta_value` of a `meta_key` that has the value of `user_address`.

One way to do this, to change the foreach loop in php to:

```
foreach($row as $rec)
    {
        $json_array[$rec['meta_key']]=$rec['meta_value'];
        array_push($json_data,$json_array);
    }
```

Now, if you dump that array, it will look like:

```
array(
    ...
    [10] => array (
        'user_address' => '26 Aorile Costo'
    ),
    ...
)
```

And you can reference to it in javascript with `data[i].user_address`

You could also get rid of the `array_push`, and just output the `$json_array`, so you wont have to walk the array in javascript, and can reference to it simply as `data.user_address`, because the array dump will now look like:

```
array(
    ...
    'user_address' => '26 Aorile Costo',
    ...
)
```

Comment: Hi Stretch, thanks for your answer. I've added `$json_array['user_address']=$rec['user_address'];` (do I need to leave `$json_array['meta_key']=$rec['meta_key']`; or not?) .... and replaced `data[i]` with `data[i].user_address`. But it says NULL

Comment: Changed my answer, hope it makes more sense

Comment: it does make sense, but unfortunately now I get: **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data**
`var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. 
Changed from

```
$row=$db->prepare('select * from wp_usermeta');
```

to

```
$row=$db->prepare('select * from wp_usermeta where meta_key = "user_address"')
```

Then i've changed :

```
$json_array['meta_key']=$rec['meta_key'];
```

to

```
$json_array['meta_value']=$rec['meta_value'];
```

and data[i] becomes data[i].meta_value

Comment: Cool ... But I would definitely look at not using array_push, and setting the meta_key as the array key, and the meta_value as the value, which would mean you can reference it simply as data.user_address (and the same with the rest of the meta keys)

Comment: The solution you've provided before was giving me **SyntaxError: JSON.parse**. I'll be happy to use your solution if I don't get that error. Any thoughts? :)

Comment: Yeah sure, my first thought is that you have a PHP error, which is making the responceText unreadable to JSON.parse. Could you run the php script on it's own, and see if it outputs any errors ... (It has to be completely clean, just the JSON array that prints)

Comment: Or, as @alexis touched upon, do a `console.log(data.resonseText);` before the json.parse, and see if it is formatted properly.

Comment: Console log reports a blank space .. let me see if I can add a screenshot .. one sec  @Stretch

Comment: @Stretch here the screenshot from the console:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28834536/Screen-Shot-2015-04-28-at-11.51.18.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76440/discussion-between-joe-and-stretch).